# How do I toggle between stylesheets by pressing Enter on the keyboard using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, toggle, stylesheet, keyboard-events

**TL;DR version**
Trying to toggle from one stylesheet to the next one in line, using the document.styleSheets property. My code doesn't work.
Also I'm pretty new to js. So it might be a stupid question.

**HTML**  
`<form id="play">
    <input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="checkEnter(event)" value="PRESS ENTER" autofocus="">`
    

**JS**

```
   <script>  
    var styles = document.styleSheets;  
    var i = 0;  
    function checkEnter(event)
            {  
                if (event.keycode === 13 && i<=document.styleSheets.length) {

                   styles(i).disabled = true; 
                    i++; 
                    styles.item(i).disabled = false;
                }

            }
    </script>
```

I've found many answers using checkboxes, radio buttons, submit buttons,you name it... but that way the js function gets the name of the style via function parameters, which it then uses to choose the style. I want it to go like: style1 *user pressed ENTER* **BAM!** style2 *user pressed ENTER* **BAM!** style3 and so on...

I feel as if the problem lies somewhere in the 3 lines after I've checked if the user pressed enter,  but that might just be my rookie mind.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**

[Best tutorial I have found so far](http://www.codechewing.com/library/how-to-disable-or-enable-a-stylesheet-in-javascript/), but can't figure out how to make it work in my situation.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank you, followed your advice. I hope I did better on the second try.